# Can we change Command bar control display limit in crm 2013?

Tags: dynamics-crm-2013

Is there any way we can change the limit of command bar to show more than 5 buttons in crm 2013 ?

If anyone have idea kindly share.

Answer (score 1):

The Dynamics CRM Spring'14 update increases the visible buttons to 7 ... Other than that, there is no way to change it. If you have more, the dots will still show everything else as it is now.

Answer (score 0):

The limit is 5 (7 in Spring '14 release as Alex pointed out), additional buttons will be always listed in the overflow section (the three dots)

Comment: Thanks for your immediate response